# "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item" when using longtable

Tags: latex, longtable

I have to make a table that is quite long so I use the `longtable` package. The following code gives me the `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item` error for the `\begin{center}` line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}


        \begin{longtable}[H]{c|c|c|c|c|c}
            \begin{center}
                    \hline
                    \textbf{ID projet} & \textbf{Nom du projet} & \textbf{Complexité} & \textbf{Disponibilité des données} & \textbf{Coût} & \textbf{Impact}  \\
                    \hline
                    cell & cell  & cell & cell  & cell & cell  \\
                    \hline
                    cell  & cell  & cell & cell & cell &cell \\   
                    \hline
                    cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
                    \hline
                    cell & cell & cell &  cell & cell & cell \\
                    \hline
                    cell & cell & cell& cell & cell & cell \\
                    \hline
                    cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
                    \hline
                    cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
                    \hline
            \end{center}
        \end{longtable}
```

I don't know if it's related but the first `\hline` gives me the `Misplaced \noalign` error and the `\textbf` line gives me the `Misplaced \omit` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not hide the content of your longtable inside a `center` environment. If you want the table to be centred, you can use the optional `[c]` argument. However this won't make a visual difference because your table does not fit within the available text width.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

        \begin{longtable}[c]{c|c|c|c|c|c}
                    \hline
                    \textbf{ID projet} & \textbf{Nom du projet} & \textbf{Complexité} & \textbf{Disponibilité des données} & \textbf{Coût} & \textbf{Impact}  \\
                    \hline
                    cell & cell  & cell & cell  & cell & cell  \\
                    \hline
                    cell  & cell  & cell & cell & cell &cell \\   
                    \hline
                    cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
                    \hline
                    cell & cell & cell &  cell & cell & cell \\
                    \hline
                    cell & cell & cell& cell & cell & cell \\
                    \hline
                    cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
                    \hline
                    cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
                    \hline
        \end{longtable}

        \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've spent hours trying to figure out what the problem was lol